# ExtJS : How to map Store fields to JSON properties?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, data-binding

I have the following JSON data :

```
{
  "disclaimer": "Exchange rates provided for informational purposes only and do not constitute financial advice of any kind. Although every attempt is made to ensure quality, no guarantees are made of accuracy, validity, availability, or fitness for any purpose. All usage subject to acceptance of Terms: https://openexchangerates.org/terms/",
  "license": "Data sourced from various providers; resale prohibited; no warranties given of any kind. All usage subject to License Agreement: https://openexchangerates.org/license/",
  "timestamp": 1475110853,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 3.672983,
    "AFN": 66.5538,
    "ALL": 122.0421,
    "AMD": 473.5925,
    "ANG": 1.7763,
    "AOA": 165.571834,
    "ARS": 15.3169,
    "AUD": 1.299338,
    "AWG": 1.792667,
    "YER": 250.130999,
    "ZAR": 13.61321,
    "ZMK": 5252.024745,
    "ZMW": 9.831204,
    "ZWL": 322.387247
  }
}
```

And I have defined my model as follows:

```
Ext.define('CurrencyConvert.model.CurrencyCode', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [
        {
            name : 'code',
            value : 'string'
        },
        {
            name : 'rate',
            value : 'float'
        }
    ]
});
```

So that I can have the currency code(i.e. "USD") and the rate. But the problem is that the currency code itself is the property name of the actual rate; so how would I create my store so as to get both the code and the rate in my model ?

Ex:
For `"AED": 3.672983`, I want the `code` value to hold "AED" and `rate` field to hold 3.672983.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
    Ext.define('CurrencyConvert.model.CurrencyCode', {
        extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields : [
            {
                name : 'code',
                value : 'string',
                convert:function(v,rec){
                   === Add Your Logic Here ===
                }
            },
            {
                name : 'rate',
                value : 'float'
                convert:function(v,rec){
                   === Add Your Logic Here ===
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: And the logic is ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('CurrencyConvert.model.CurrencyCode', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [
        {
            name : 'code',
            value : 'string'
        },
        {
            name : 'rate',
            value : 'float', 
            convert : function(value, record) {
                return jsonData.rates[record.get('code')]
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: This is only a partial fix. I figured the best way to do this is to load the store manually using regular javascript to get the codes and rates.